# My blutooth device not work in KUBUNTU

Tags: drivers, kubuntu

The blutooth device doesn't detects any devices neither it is being detected by any other devices.

the blutooth buttons just disable & enable the blutooth software but it doesn't work atall

Comment: You will first have to find out which bluetooth device you are using. Perhaps this is of help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We may need some more information to help you: What brand/model is this bluetooth device? Which driver do you use?

Comment: We need a bit more information to help you solve this problem. Can you give us what type of Bluetooth device it is? What type of Bluetooth chip do you have?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, then I solved it this way:

1. Turn off Bluetooth.
2. Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo service bluetooth restart`.
3. Turn on Bluetooth.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try that